# How to target .NET 4.0 under mono

Tags: .net, mono

I have mono 2.10 installed which is said to support 4.0
i have a site running, a simple hello world that is built (i develop in on a windows box with vs 2010 and then upload to a linux box) with 3.5.

I want to put the site under 4.0.
I changed it on visual studio and on the windows box it works. on linux i have the error

Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'

SO, which steps are needed to change the target from 3.5 to 4.0?

EDIT: Am not using monodevelop.

Am creating the site on a windows machine with visual studio and then copying the entire website folder to the linux box. After that i open the site url and thats it.

WHen should i run the dmcs  compiler? AFAIK the site is compiled automatically when it runs for the first time ?

Comment: It sounds a little like you are implicitly including monodevelop in your question. What version of MonoDevelop do you have?

Comment: Exacly. In such case consider using xbuild.

Comment: dup? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8739406/targeting-and-compiling-for-net-framework-4-0-with-mono

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although it is correct that you use `dmcs` to compile .NET 4 apps on Mono, I do not think that this is your problem. It sounds to me like you are trying to serve a compiled ASP.NET app on Linux.

Your problem is probably that you need to call mod-mono-server4 from Apache but are likely running mod-mono-server2. You should have a line in your httpd.conf or mod-mono.conf that looks like the following:

```
MonoServerPath default /usr/bin/mod-mono-server4
```

Check out [this page](http://mono-project.com/Mod_mono), specifically the troubleshooting section. The instructions are a little dated so you have to change the digit '2' to '4' but it is a good explanation of what is going on. [This page](http://go-mono.com/config-mod-mono/) might also help you setup the right configuration.

Answer (score 3):

Using mono 2.10, you either run `dmcs` or `gmcs -sdk:4` when compiling your code.