# Targeting and Compiling For .NET Framework 4.0 with Mono

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, mono

Generally the Managed executables I compile with the Mono GMCS on Ubuntu, run fine with .NET Framework 2.0 on Windows, but don't work with any other version. Is it possible to compile exes that run on the .NET Framework 4 with Mono?

Comment: Hey there, could you either request more informations, or accept an answer?

Comment: @JbEvain Sorry, I meant to accept your question, I forgot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `gmcs`, use the `dmcs` front end of the Mono compiler which targets the 4.0 runtime.